# Error receiving broadcast Intent caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have this code for a Cordova plugin that tries to scan a barcode and send back the result:

```
public class Scan extends CordovaPlugin {

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;
    private Intent intentService = new Intent("com.hyipc.core.service.barcode.BarcodeService2D");
    private String strBarcode = "";
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;


    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("scan")) {
            scan();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void scan() {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("action_barcode_broadcast");

        if (this.receiver == null) {
            this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                     if(intent.getAction().equals("action_barcode_broadcast")) {
                         strBarcode = intent.getExtras().getString("key_barcode_string");
                         callbackContext.success(strBarcode);
                     }
                 }

             };
             cordova.getActivity().startService(intentService);
             cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
         }
     }
 }
```

When I run it, my app crashes and I get this in the logs:

```
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=action_barcode_broadcast flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.plugin.Scan$1@414f29f0
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:798)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at com.example.plugin.Scan$1.onReceive(Scan.java:74)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:788)
07-18 08:53:28.583: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     ... 9 more
07-18 08:53:28.608: E/AppErrorDialog(586): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
07-18 08:53:28.640: E/jdwp(2401): Failed sending reply to debugger: Success
07-18 08:53:29.221: E/AEE/DUMPSTATE(2424): copy_file: Copy /data/anr/2345.hprof to PROCESS_OOME_HPROF failed(2), No such file or directory
07-18 08:53:30.547: E/AEE/DUMPSTATE(2424): copy_file: Copy /proc/gpulog to SYS_GPU_INFO failed(2), No such file or directory
07-18 08:53:33.084: E/AEE/DUMPSTATE(2446): copy_process: execv /system/xbin/proc_mem failed(2), No such file or directory
07-18 08:53:33.097: E/AEE/DUMPSTATE(2447): copy_process: execv /system/bin/dmlog failed(2), No such file or directory
07-18 08:53:34.130: E/jdwp(2401): Failed sending reply to debugger: Success
```

Line 74, which the log indicates that it's causing the error, is the one in which I'm calling `callbackContext.success` method. I'm sure that `strBarcode` exists, because I can log it in the `onReceive` function.

Comment: try adding `intentService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Comment: Where should I add it? Sorry, I'm new to Android and Java

Comment: just before starting the `cordova.getActivity().startService(intentService);` service

Comment: I've added it, but I get the same error

Comment: put `Log.d("BarCode", intent.getExtras().getString("key_barcode_string"));`just before assigning value from intent to `strBarcode` and check if the value is available when receiving intent.

Comment: I've done this, it's available

Comment: Also can you post your `CallbackContext` class

Comment: CallbacContext comes from import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext; I've saw that that's what you use to send data back to JavaScript in Cordova Plugins

Comment: Ok i think.. You need to add. `callbackContext = new CallbackContext();`

Comment: and then call `callbackContext.success(strBarcode);`

Comment: I will post this as an answer , If it worked please appreciate by accepting the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating an object for `CallbackContext` But not initializing it by calling the default constructor for the class.. 
Thats y the `null pointer exception` is occurring

So try this way

```
public void scan(CallbackContext context) {
    this.callbackContext = context;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("action_barcode_broadcast");

    if (this.receiver == null) {
        this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 if(intent.getAction().equals("action_barcode_broadcast")) {
                     strBarcode = intent.getExtras().getString("key_barcode_string");
                     callbackContext.success(strBarcode);
                 }
             }

         };
         cordova.getActivity().startService(intentService);
         cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
     }
 }
```

This will fix the `Null pointer Exception`

**EDIT**

the issue was that the returned `callbackContext` and your created `callbackContext` are of same name.. So modify the `scan()`

So that it will look some thing like this

```
 scan(callbackContext);
```

and inside the function

```
public void scan(CallbackContext clBackCtxt) {
  this.callbackContext = clBackCtxt;

   // your rest code
```

Comment: When I try this, I get this at the build step:
 error: constructor CallbackContext in class CallbackContext cannot be applied to given types;
                        callbackContext = new CallbackContext();
                                          ^
  required: String,CordovaWebView
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Are you using Android studio? @AlexandruPufan

Comment: No, it's a plugin for an Ionic app

Comment: @AlexandruPufan . .I have found the problem

Comment: @AlexandruPufan Thanks.. Happie coding